# Is the dimension of a lattice equal to the number of its basis vectors or the number of coordinates in a basis vector?

Tags: matrix-rank, integer-lattices

$\newcommand\L{\mathcal{L}}\newcommand\b{\mathbf{b}}$
I always thought that the dimension of a lattice is equal to the number of vectors in its basis. I. e.,
$$
\L(\b_1,...,\b_n)= \left\{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\b_i:x_i \in \mathbb{Z}\right\}
$$
has dimension $n$. This belief was due to,

1. Hoffstein, Jeffrey, et al. *An Introduction to Cryptography* (pg. 388). Springer New York, 2014.

> The *dimension* of $\L$ is the number of vectors in a basis for $\L$.

2. [Gama, Nicolas, and Phong Q. Nguyen. *Predicting Lattice Reduction.*](https://www.iacr.org/archive/eurocrypt2008/49650031/49650031.pdf)

> $\L$ is equal to the set $\L(\b_1,...,\b_d)= \left\{\sum_{i=1}^d x_i\b_i:x_i \in \mathbb{Z}\right\}$ of all integer linear combinations of the $\b_i$'s. The integer $d$ is the dimension of the lattice $\L$.

Note that in Gama et al. we have $d=n$.

However, recently, while reading,

3. Micciancio, Daniele, and Shafi Goldwasser. Complexity of lattice problems: a cryptographic perspective. Vol. 671. Springer Science & Business Media, 2002.

page 1 has the same equation (the first one in this post) and says,

> A *lattice* in $\mathbb{R}^m$ is the set of all integral combinations of $n$ linearly independent vectors $\b_1,...\b_n$ in $\mathbb{R}^m (m\geq n)$. The integers $n$ and $m$ are called the *rank* and *dimension* of the lattice, respectively.

So it seems that what the first two definitions call dimension, this third definition calls rank! E. g., The lattice $\L(\b_1), \b_1=[0, 1]$ is one dimensional according to the first two definitions and two dimensional according to the third while having a rank of 1.

Could someone clarify if there no standard it depends on the author or am I missing something?

Comment: It makes sense to me that dimension/rank may be conflated in contexts where only the rank is important to the discussion, because (1) in many contexts, lattices are full-rank anyway, and (2) lattices are akin to vector subspaces, and in general linear algebra, rank/dimension can be understood as synonyms. All in all, I wouldn't worry too much about it, whether "dimension = rank of lattice" or "dimension = dimension of ambient Euclidean space."

Comment: I see, btw, what do you mean by, "dimension of ambient Euclidean space?"

Comment: "Ambient" space for a vector space/manifold/etc. is the target space of your object's embedding. For example, the circle S^1 lives in R^2 as the locus x^2 + y^2 = 1, and you would say R^2 is the ambient space of this embedding.